# SQL Query Optimization (NOT IN Clause) Multible tables

Tags: mysql, mariadb

**Hello Community!**

is there a way to optimize this **SQL Query** so that it is **faster**? For Example:

Pseudo:

[...] NOT IN (table1, table2, table3, ...)

The Query in question:

```
SELECT data FROM _ WHERE p_=:e 
                            AND status <= 1 
                            AND s_ >= :f  
                            AND c_ IS NULL
                            AND _.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM c_)
                            AND _.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM p_)
                            AND _.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM e_)
                            AND _.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM f_)
                            AND _.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM w_)
                            AND _.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM a_)
                            AND _.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM k_)
                            AND _.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM w_)
                            AND _.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM r_) ORDER BY s_ DESC
```

Comment: yes of course. just get rid of this horrible database schema

Comment: Now that you mantion it ... i have the urge to smash my head against the keyboard :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exists may help eg

```
AND _.id NOT exists (SELECT 1  FROM c_ where c_.id = _.id )
```